# duda ordenamiento con listas paraleas

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for

Hola buenas tengo un ejercicio el cual estoy intentado entender pero aun sigo en en el hoyo

se trata de ordenar 2 listas paralelas de nombres de alumnos y sus respectivas notas y ordenarlos de mayor a menor, bueno empezamos creando 2 listas vacias para introducir por teclado los nombres y las notas

```
alumnos=[]
notas=[]
for x in range(5):
  nom=input("Introduc los nombres: ")
  alumnos.append(nom)
  calificaciones=int(input("Introduce las notas "))
  notas.append(calificaciones)
"""
Mi duda comienza desde aqui al crear dos blucles for
"""
for k in range(4): #Aqui entiendo al ser 5 complementos restamos -1
   for x in range(4-k): #Porque resta a k?
       if notas[x]<notas[x+1]: #No entiendo desde aqui lo que hace la condicion if
          aux1=notas[x] #Tengo conocimiento que es una variable auxiliar
          notas[x]=notas[x+1]
          notas[x+1]=aux1
          aux2=alumnos[x]
          alumnos[x]=alumnos[x+1]
          alumnos[x+1]=aux2
print("Lista de alumnos y sus notas ordenadas de mayor a menor")
for x in range(5): #Porque es necesario otravez recorrer la lista?
    print(alumnos[x],notas[x])
```

Salida seria asi:

```
  Lista de alumnos y sus notas ordenadas de mayor a menor

 Pepe 10
 Juan 7
 Alex 5
 Carlos 3
 Pablo 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo, el algoritmo que está usando  es el más que conocido  [ordenamiento de burbuja](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja).

El algoritmo es bastante simple, la idea es que en cada iteración sobre la lista un elemento queda ordenado definitivamente "subiéndolo" al final de la lista, por eso el primer `for`  itera `n - 1` veces (siendo `n` la longitud de la lista). Tu lista es de 5 elementos por lo que con 4 iteraciones queda seguro ordenada, por eso el primer `for` es `for k in range(4):`.

---

Ten en cuenta que `range` genera valores hasta el valor de su argumento `end` menos uno. El valor inicial del rango está incluido, pero el final no:

```
>>> list(range(4))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> list(range(2, 4))
[2, 3]
>>> list(range(1, 10, 2))
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

---

En cada iteración del primer `for` recorremos la lista tomando parejas de elementos consecutivos (para lo cual se usa el valor `x` generado por el segundo `for` como índice, `notas[x]` y `notas[x+1]`), si el primero es menor que el segundo (`if notas[x]<notas[x+1]`) los intercambia de lugar, ya que el orden de la lista es descendente y por tanto no puede haber un elemento que tenga otro menor inmediatamente situado a la derecha.

Dado que en cada iteración sabemos que un elemento queda ordenado al final de la lista, no tiene sentido en la siguiente iteración comprobar los que están ordenados, es decir, en la primera iteración comprobamos desde el primer elemento hasta el último, en la segunda desde el primero hasta el penúltimo, en la tercera desde el primero hasta el antepenúltimo, etc. Esta es la causa de que el segundo `for` itere desde el índice 0 hasta el índice `4 - k` en tu caso.

El intercambio de valores lo hacen las líneas:

- `aux1=notas[x]`: almacena temporalmente el valor del elemento con índice `x`.
- `notas[x]=notas[x+1]`: le damos al elemento con índice `x` el valor del elemento que tiene a su derecha (índice `x+1`).
- `notas[x+1]=aux1`: le damos al elemento con índice `x+1` el valor que tenía originalmente el elemento en posición `x` .

esto se puede simplificar en Python para evitar el uso de una variable auxiliar que almacene temporalmente el valor del primer elemento haciendo simplemente:

```
lista[x], lista[x + 1] = lista[x + 1], lista[x]
```

La forma en como se recorre reiteradamente el array es lo que da nombre al algoritmo, ya que recuerda por ejemplo a como ascienden las burbujas de aire desde el fondo de  un recipiente de agua. Las "burbujas" son las parejas consecutivas de elementos que se van comprobando.

Vamos a verlo  mejor con un ejemplo simplificado a una sola lista y basado en tu código:

```
lista = [1, 3, 4, 8, 2]

# len(lista) obtiene el número de elementos de la lista (5 en este caso)
for k in range(len(lista) - 1):  
    for x in range(len(lista)  - 1 - k):
        if lista[x] < lista[x + 1]:
            lista[x], lista[x + 1] = lista[x + 1], lista[x]
```

Estos son los pasos que va a seguir el código anterior:

> - **`k` = 0**, lista original `[1, 3, 4, 8, 2]`:
>
>   - **`x` = 0**: Comparamos si el primer elemento (1) es menor que el segundo (3). Como lo es los intercambiamos de lugar:
>
>     ```
>     [3, 1, 4, 8, 2]
>     ```
>   - **`x` = 1**: Comparamos si el segundo elemento (1) es menor que el tercero (4). Como lo es los intercambiamos de lugar:
>
>     ```
>     [3, 4, 1, 8, 2]
>     ```
>   - **`x` = 2**: Comparamos si el tercero elemento (1) es menor que el cuarto (8). Como lo es los intercambiamos de lugar:
>
>     ```
>     [3, 4, 8, 1, 2]
>     ```
>   - **`x` = 3**: Comparamos si el cuarto elemento (1) es menor que el quinto (2). Como lo es los intercambiamos de lugar:
>
>     ```
>     [3, 4, 8, 2, 1]
>     ```
> - **`k` = 1**, tenemos ordenados 1 elemento:
>
>   - **`x` = 0**: Comparamos si el primer elemento (3) es menor que el segundo (4). Como lo es los intercambiamos de lugar:
>
>     ```
>     [4, 3, 8, 2, 1]
>     ```
>   - **`x` = 1**: Comparamos si el segundo elemento (3) es menor que el tercero (8). Como lo es los intercambiamos de lugar:
>
>     ```
>     [4, 8, 3, 2, 1]
>     ```
>   - **`x` = 2**: Comparamos si el tercero elemento (3) es menor que el cuarto (2). Como es mayor no hacemos nada:
>
>     ```
>     [4, 8, 2, 3, 1]
>     ```
> - **`k` = 2**, tenemos ordenados 2 elementos:
>
>   - **`x` = 0**: Comparamos si el primer elemento (4) es menor que el segundo (8). Como lo es los intercambiamos de lugar:
>
>     ```
>     [8, 4, 2, 3, 1]
>     ```
>   - **`x` = 1**: Comparamos si el segundo elemento (4) es menor que el tercero (2). Como es mayor no hacemos nada:
>
>     ```
>     [8, 2, 4, 3, 1]
>     ```
> - **`k` = 3**, tenemos ordenados 3 elementos:
>
>   - **`x` = 0**: Comparamos si el primer elemento (8) es menor que el segundo (2). Como es mayor no hacemos nada:
>
>     ```
>     [2, 8, 4, 3, 1]
>     ```

En tu caso ordenas dos listas a la vez pero en función de `notas` solo, es decir, aplicas el ordenamiento burbuja sobre `notas`, solo que cuando  intercambias dos valores en `notas` también lo haces también con los elementos correspondientes de  en alumnos. Esto realmente se podría simplificar mucho usando en vez de dos listas separadas una lista de listas  por ejemplo y usando el método `list.sort`.

El último `for` simplemente imprime el resultado, con ambas listas una vez ordenadas, no tiene nada que ver con el algoritmo en sí.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y explicación me ayudaste a verlo más claro

Answer (score 0):

1. La razon del segundo for con (4-k) es por eficiencia.  Cuando k vale 0 vas a comparar todos los elementos, pero cuando k vale 1, el menor elemento de la lista ya tiene que estar en la ultima posicion, por lo que no es necesario compararlo.
2. La condicion if compara el elemento en la posicion x con el elemento en la posicion x + 1.  Si x < x+1 entonces los cambia de lugar.
3. El ultimo for que recorre la lista simplemente es para imprimir el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Me permito poner algunos comentarios sobre su código para explicar el mismo:

```css
for k in range(4):  # R/ta: El rango que se genera va del 0 al 4 correspondiente a los 5 elementos de cada lista.
   for x in range(4-k):  # La idea de poner 4-k es que se vaya tomando los siguientes valores al hacer el recorrido: (4-0 = 4) inicialmente, luego (4-1 = 3), (4-2 = 2) (4-3 = 1) y por ultimo (4 - 4 = 0), con el fin que la comparación que se hace más adelante no presente error al tomar el último elemento+1, como lo indica alanfcm no es necesario tomar la última posición para comparar con una posición siguiente a ella (jeje... no es posible).
       if notas[x] < notas[x+1]:  # Toma la primera nota guardada en la lista y valida si la siguiente nota es mayor, luego hace lo mismo con la demás notas siguiendo el flujo del ciclo for establecido para x.
            aux1 = notas[x]  # Guardas temporalmente el valor de la primera nota en la variable auxiliar, pues el valor de la primera nota será reemplazado, para ir ordenando la nota mayor en la posición uno de la lista, esto se varias veces de acuerdo al flujo del ciclo for establecido para x.
            notas[x] = notas[x+1]  # Ahora reemplazas el valor de la primera nota por la nota segunda nota de la lista, sabiendo que el valor de la primera nota no se perderá, pues ya lo guardamos antes en aux1.
            notas[x+1] = aux1  # Finalmente el valor que está en aux1 (de la primera nota) lo asignamos a la segunda nota, teniendo de este modo ya organizada de mayor a menor la primera y segunda nota de la lista, siguiendo el flujo del ciclo for establecido para x.
            aux2 = alumnos[x]  # Luego se aplica la misma lógica con reemplazo (torres de Hanoi) con el nombre del alumno.
            alumnos[x] = alumnos[x+1]
            alumnos[x+1] = aux2
print("Lista de alumnos y sus notas ordenadas de mayor a menor")
for x in range(5):  # Terminadas las iteraciones en los ciclos for, los alumnos ya se encuentran organizados de mayor a menor de acuerdo a sus notas, por lo cual solo queda mostrar el resultado, se recorren entonces las dos listas en un solo ciclo for para ir imprimiendo uno a uno sus valores.
    print(alumnos[x],notas[x])
```